# TypeScript: How to import file into index.ts without getting undefined for data

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I currently have this logic:

```
import { readFileSync } from "fs";

export class Data {
  Address: string;
  General_Plan_Designation: string;
  Latitude: number;
  Longitude: number;

  static DELIMITER = ",";

  constructor(rawRow: string) {
    const data = rawRow.split(Data.DELIMITER);

    this.Address = data[0];
    this.General_Plan_Designation = data[1];
    this.Latitude = parseFloat(data[2]);
    this.Longitude = parseFloat(data[3]);
  }
}

const ROW_DELIMITER = "\r\n";

const rawData = readFileSync("src/Cales_trim_down.csv", {
  encoding: "utf-8",
});

const data: Data[] = [];

for (const rawRow of rawData.split(ROW_DELIMITER)) {
  data.push(new Data(rawRow));
}
```

Which successfully console logs the following:

```
[start:run]   Address {
[start:run]     Address: '138 Stockton Ave',
[start:run]     Latitude: 37.3327991,
[start:run]     Longitude: -121.9040357
[start:run]   },
[start:run]   Address {
[start:run]     Address: '641 N Capitol Av ',
[start:run]     Latitude: 37.3762739,
[start:run]     Longitude: -121.8496285
[start:run]   },
[start:run]   Address {
[start:run]     Address: '535 N 7th St ',
[start:run]     Latitude: 37.348071,
[start:run]     Longitude: -121.8911488
[start:run]   },
[start:run]   Address {
[start:run]     Address: '750 W San Carlos St ',
[start:run]     Latitude: 37.3234717,
[start:run]     Longitude: -121.9044348
[start:run]   },
```

I placed it in its own `Data.ts` file and then imported it into the `index.ts` file, but if I do it like so:

```
import { Data } from "./Data";

const data = new Data('Cales_trim_down.csv');

console.log(data);
```

I have to pass in some argument, such as the csv file as a string and then I get this data strucutre:

```
    Data {Address: "Cales_trim_down.csv", General_Plan_Designation: undefined, Latitude: NaN, Longitude: NaN}
     Address: "Cales_trim_down.csv"
     General_Plan_Designation: undefined
     Latitude: NaN
     Longitude: NaN
     __proto__: Object
```

Totally different than what I had before. What is the best way to import that `Data` class back into the root file of my project without losing the integrity of the data being console logged?

It would be ideal if I did not have to pass in the `Cales_trim_down.csv` to the instance of `Data`, but I have not been able to refactor the `Data` class in such a way where I do not have to pass any arguments to the constructor. Declaring `filename` ahead of time does not resolve it.

My other thought is I am not supposed to pass in the string of `cales_trim_down.csv` but `rawData`, but when I do that, it tells me it cannot find `rawData`.

Comment: The only thing i can tell is that you are not using the default export when the component is titled as though you should be, but I dunno if that helps.

Comment: @AlexanderHemming, yeah the only thing that does is not make it a named export anymore so I don't need the curly braces, but still have the issue with the instance needing an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first instance, you're feeding a *single row* of data to the `Data` constructor within the `for` loop.  The data is loaded in using `readFileSync("src/Cales_trim_down.csv")`.  In the second instance, you're feeding the `new Data` a string which is the location of the file.  These are two totally different arguments. In the second situation, your `Data` instance is not actually reading in any data, which is why all the values are undefined. It has nothing to do with the fact that you're modularizing the `Data` class, but with what you're using to create a `new Data` instance.

Define your Data class in its own file:

```js
// Data.ts
export class Data {
  // ... all the same logic as before
}
```

Then use the same logic you had before:

```
import { Data } from "./Data";

// const data = new Data('Cales_trim_down.csv'); <--- No!

const ROW_DELIMITER = "\r\n";

const rawData = readFileSync("src/Cales_trim_down.csv", {
  encoding: "utf-8",
});

const data: Data[] = [];

for (const rawRow of rawData.split(ROW_DELIMITER)) {
  data.push(new Data(rawRow));
}
```

#### Edit: Keeping it in the Class

Another option, probably cleaner, is to keep all these data-related methods within the data class itself:

```js
// Data.ts
import { readFileSync } from "fs";

export class Data {
  rawData: string;
  data: {
    Address: string;
    General_Plan_Designation: string;
    Latitude: number;
    Longitude: number;
  }[];

  static DELIMITER = ",";
  static ROW_DELIMITER = "\n";

  constructor(filepath: string) {
    this.rawData = readFileSync(filepath, {
      encoding: "utf-8"
    });
    this.data = [];
    this.processData();
  }

  processData() {
    for (const rawRow of this.rawData.split(Data.ROW_DELIMITER)) {
      this.processRow(rawRow);
    }
  }

  processRow(rowstring: string) {
    const rowarray = rowstring.split(Data.DELIMITER);
    const formattedRow = {
      Address: rowarray[0],
      General_Plan_Designation: rowarray[1],
      Latitude: Number(rowarray[2]),
      Longitude: Number(rowarray[3])
    };
    this.data.push(formattedRow);
  }
}

// SomewherElse.ts

const filepath = path.resolve(__dirname, "sampledata.txt");
const myData = new Data(filepath);
console.log(myData.data);
```

### [Working Node TS Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/node-ts-data-class-pmgzx)

So now all data methods, including reading in the data, parsing the rows, etc., are all contained *within* the Data class.  I think this will be much neater.

Also, it looks like you're trying to convert a CSV to JSON with this code?  Surely there must be some library out there that does that already?

Comment: indeed. I was just about to add an answer, I had to pass in `rawData` to the instance, but that would give me an error, but all I had to do was export that variable. I will mark your answer but add a supplementary answer.

Comment: oh interesting, your answer, looks like it will work even better than mine, since it only solves one half of the problem.

Comment: I mean there's alot of ways to do it.  Depending on how you want to use data, I would consider writing a method on `Data` that *does* take in the file path and handles the looping for you, all contained within the class.  Just depends on what you're doing

Comment: well your solution solved both my issues. I was going to pass in `rawData` int the instance of `Data` after exporting the variable, but would still have been left with undefined all over the place, your solution, while it may repeat some logic, gives me a better solution in that it is looping through all the data, perfect, thank you.

Comment: is there a way to do this where I still maintain an instance of that Data  class? I am going to eventually need it to pass it to another instance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking

Comment: so you said no to this, `const data = new Data('Cales_trim_down.csv');`, but my intention was to pass `data` into `customMap.addAddressMarker();`. Given your answer, how do I accomplish that now? Because I could not just pass in `data`.

Comment: I edited my answer with some ideas and a sandbox